# how to make opaque background for a TextView

Tags: android, textview

See picture: [image: picture]

How to make that the line of the cell (this is editText) does not cross out the background of the TextView? Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="1280dp"
    android:layout_height="720dp">


        <TextView
         
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="492dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="191dp"
            android:text="TEXT VIEW"
            android:textColor="#2955D8"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
          
            android:layout_width="326dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="201dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:ems="10"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: could you please include enough code for others to recreate this problem ?

Comment: thanks for advice. I added the code.

Comment: are you sure you want to use a textview and an edit text like this instead of using TextInputLayout ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody didn't think about TextInputLayout. Tell me please how can I implement it?

Comment: i'm sure you can find sufficient resources available for it online :)

Comment: thanks. I found another way to do it